# Is the group $U(8)$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Referring to the group of units.

My first thought is yes, since $1$ would be the generator.

Although I think I'm getting confused between the generator and the identity element in this case. $1$ is definitely the latter, is it also a generator?

I believe I'm doing the operation incorrectly. For example, $3 \cdot 3 =1$ correct? $3$ couldn't be the generator because if I kept doing this operation I would start repeating the same elements, but not all the elements ($1,3,5,7)$

Comment: @CameronWilliams But 1 is indeed the identity in this case. I have the Cayley table in front of me and anything (1,3,5,7) operated with 1 will result in the operated element (ie 1,3,5,7)

Comment: Note that $3^2=5^2=7^2=1$ so there is no single generator.

Comment: @DerekHolt but none of those elements will produce all the other elements in the group?

Comment: NO @Mukr....how could it? All the non-unit elements haver order two, so none has order four. In fact, $\;U_8\cong C_2\times C_2\;$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you are mixing $\mathbb{Z_8}$ and $U(8)$. $1$ is identity in $U(8)$ as operation is multiplication here. But in $\mathbb{Z_8}$ operation is addition, so $0$ is the identity and $1$ is the generator in $\mathbb{Z_8}$ as you can have any elements less than $8$ by adding $1$. No $U(8)$ is not cyclic. To see it pick an element of $U(8)$ and keep multiplying it with itself. If you find one with order 4, that is your generator. but every element here is of order 2.

$\textbf{Theorem-}$ $U(n)$ is cyclic iff $n$= $2,4, p^k,2p^k $ where $p$ is an odd prime.
Try to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

$U(8)$ is not cyclic because it has more than one element of order $2$ namely $3,5,7$ and in general $U((2^n)$ is not cyclic for $n>2$.