# Find a non-cyclic subgroup of order $4$ in $U(40).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find a non-cyclic subgroup of order $4$ in $U(40).$

I've got no idea how to approach this problem.

I've listed the whole group of $U(40)$ and picked $4$ elements to see if they made a subgroup but the trial and error method isn't working out.

The part that seems too be causing the most problems is the closure part; I can't find $4$ elements that when I multiply them they give me back only elements I started with.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\mathbb Z/40\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z.$

$\{1,3,5,7\}$ is a non-cyclic group of order $4$ mod $8$.

Can you find elements in $U(40)$ that are $\{1,3,5,7\}$ mod $8$ and $1$ mod $5$?

Comment: More hint:  $(10n+1)^2\equiv1\bmod40$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $U(40)\cong U(8)\times U(5)\cong (C_2\times C_2)\times C_4$.

Reference:

[Is the group $U(8)$ cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954823/is-the-group-u8-cyclic)

Answer (score 0):

A non-cyclic group of order 4 is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb  Z_2$. This is generated by two commuting elements of order 2: that's what you need to look for.

For instance: it is easy to get a $2\times2$ unitary of order two, say $W=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Now you can construct $$ U=\begin{bmatrix} W&0\\0&I_{38}\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ V=\begin{bmatrix} I_2&0&0\\0&W&0\\0&0&I_{36}\end{bmatrix}
$$