# Show that $U(17)$ is a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

In this answer, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954823/is-the-group-u8-cyclic), a theorem is stated which says,

**Theorem**-  $U(n)$ is cyclic iff $n= 2,4,p^k,2p^k$ where p is an odd prime.

For $U(17)$, it doesn't satisfy any of the $n$ conditions stated in the theorem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes it does satisfy the conditions : it is of the form $p^k$ with $p=17,k=1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $$k=1.{}{}{}{}{}{}$$